# Why output value is cut when adParamInputOutput is used?

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I have stored procedure which has `VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT` parameter. The parameter is used to both pass and return large string value.

It is working perfectly when it is executed in the context of the `SQL Server Management Studio`.

The issue appears only in the `ASP page`. Here is the code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CSV", adBStr, adParamInputOutput, -1, 'some very large string goes here')
```

I am able to pass a large value (more then 4000 symbols) but the return value is cut. I have try to replace the `adBStr` with  `adLongVarWChar` and `adLongVarChar` but I get the following error:

```
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete
information was provided.
```

I guess the problem is caused by the `adParamInputOutput`. So, I am generally asking for a parameter type that will work in both direction with maximum symbols.

Comment: Is that a typo? Shouldn't it be `adLongVarWChar` and `adLongVarChar`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `adBStr` see [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) *(look at the SQL Server column)*

Comment: @Lankymart Yes. it was a typo. The `adbStr` seems to be the only type that is working as `input` and `output`.

Comment: did you try `adVarWChar`?

Comment: I was working with `MAX` values, so `adVarWChar` does not meet the requirements.